# CodeIgniter form validation config stops working when an object name is assigned

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, config

I was working with CodeIgniter's form validation. I had a config file in

```
application/config/form_validation.php
```

it works fine in most case, but in one of my files, I had this line

```
$this->load->library('form_validation', '', 'validation');
```

Then the config file stops working.

It seems to me that the config file won't work if I assigned a different object name.

That seem pretty inconvenient to me, is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but you could try:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation', null, 'validation');
```